# GCP Cloud Build ubuntu step runs successfully but without expected results

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

ubuntu returns expected results from `ls` until I add a `cd` command then it returns nothing.

Here's a truncated outline of my project structure:

```
gcp_cicd_workflow
  |-- src
     | my_module.py
  |-- tests
     | test_my_module.py
```

The log messages I'm providing below are ordered with the newest on top. Note that there's a lot of ubuntu log messages related to pulling the image that I have excluded from the log messages.

Code:

```
  # Step 4
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c', 'ls']
```

Log The `ls` command returns the expected results - it returns all the folders and files in the workspace folder:

```
Finished Step #4
Step #4: tests
Step #4: src
Step #4: setup.py
Step #4: requirements.txt
Step #4: python_cloud_builder
Step #4: gcp_cicd
Step #4: gcp.egg-info
Step #4: gcp-cicd-workflow
Step #4: cloudbuild.yaml
Step #4: __init__.py
Step #4: README.md
```

Code:

```
  # Step 4
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c', 'cd tests', 'ls']
```

Log: No results returned after the `cd` command:

```
Finished Step #4
```

Code - cd to nonexistent folder:

```
  # Step 4
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c', 'cd foo']
```

Log - Get expected "no such file ... "result):

```
Finished Step #4
Step #4: /bin/bash: line 0: cd: foo: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint`enter code here`: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c', 'cd tests; ls']
```

`$ bash -c` runs passed arguments as a single bash script. It doesn't separate passed arguments into separate scripts.

`;` in bash ends a script line, and the following after semicolon is interpreted as a new script line.

Answer (score 0):

@Christopher Janzon answer is perfect you can also do it without `entrypoint` here is a simple example

```
- id: 'set scripts_version'
  name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,SCRIPTS_VERSION_VALUE,$SHORT_SHA," k8s/*.yaml']
```